# nltk semantic word substitution

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm trying to find different ways of writing "events in [city]" which are semantically similar. I am trying to do this by finding words that are semantically similar to "events" so I can substitute them in.

To find these words I'm using nltk's wordnet corpus, but I'm getting some pretty strange results. For example, using the hyponyms of 'event.n.01', I'm getting "Miracles in Ottawa".

co-hyponyms and hypernyms seem just as bad or worse. I wonder if anyone understands the structure better and can offer a potential solution?

Here's some sample code:

```
!/usr/bin/python3

import nltk

lemma = 'event.n.01'
synset = nltk.corpus.wordnet.synset(lemma)

print("%s: %s" % (synset.name(), synset.definition()))

print("\nFinding hyponyms...")
print([s.split('.')[0] for w in synset.hyponyms() for s in w.lemma_names()])

print("\nFinding hypernym paths...")
print([s.split('.')[0] for hyprs in synset.hypernym_paths() for hypr in hyprs for s in hypr.lemma_names()])

print("\nFinding co-hyponyms...")
for hypers in synset.hypernym_paths():
        for hyper in hypers:
                print(hyper.name())
                for hypos in hyper.hyponyms():
                        print("\t%s" % (', '.join(hypos.lemma_names())))

print(synset.similar())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a deep learning approach. Train a word2vec model and get the most similar vectors to the "event" vector.

You can test a model here [Word2Vec Demo](http://turbomaze.github.io/word2vecjson/)

Answer (score 1):

The *hyponyms* of "event" are types of "event". One of them is "miracle", some others are:

```
>>> [s for w in synset.hyponyms() for s in w.lemma_names][:7]  # is 7 enough? :)
['zap', 'act', 'deed', 'human_action', 'human_activity', 'happening', 'occurrence']
```

"Event's" *hypernyms* are the oposite. Terms that "event" is a type of:

```
>>> synset.hypernyms()
[Synset('psychological_feature.n.01')]
```

You can see that "event" is one of it's *hyponyms*:

```
>>> synset.hypernyms()[0].hyponyms()
[Synset('motivation.n.01'), Synset('cognition.n.01'), Synset('event.n.01')]
```

Those are not really "similar" terms ("Psychological features in Ottawa" may seem like a correct result to a robot, but not to humans).

Perhaps it is better to go at it from a completely different angle, e.g.

```
>>> text = nltk.Text(word.lower() for word in nltk.corpus.brown.words())
>>> text.similar('event')
time day man order state way case house one place action night point
situation work year act and area audience
```

Now, take those and sort them e.g. by path_similarity:

```
>>> words = 'time day man order state way case house one place action night point'\
...         ' situation work year act and area audience'.split()
>>> 
>>> def get_symilarity(synset, word):
...     return max([synset.path_similarity(synset2)
...                for synset2 in nltk.corpus.wordnet.synsets(word)]+[0])
>>> 
>>> sorted(words, key=lambda w: get_symilarity(synset, w), reverse=True)[:5]
['act', 'case', 'action', 'time', 'way']
```

Is that a good result? I don't know. I guess it could work: "Acts in Ottawa", "Cases in New York", "Action in Rome", "Time in Tokyo", "Ways in Amsterdam"...

Comment: This reminded that it was a good idea to try and combine different methods. I found a list of search query trigrams, searched for `events` and found the most common POS tag structure (perhaps this is grammatical structure?). I then just searched for those POS tags (ex. `[n] [in] [n]`), then tried sorting them by weighting their frequency and path similarity to `events`. It was a good go, but word2vec was a lot less experimenting.

Comment: @Alter Just out of curiosity, what kind of suggstiond did you get with word2vec for "events in [city]"?

Comment: word2vec was just used on the word `events`. It worked pretty well without giving it anymore context. It had results like `racing, sporting, concerts`